# Excel column update by reading other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to update a column of excel by reading another column

like below

```
         A                    B
1     Acccess           Access Request
2     Deployment        Deployment request
```

I want column B to check column A and auto fill depending on the content in A

Comment: What have you tried so far? It appears like nothing! Did you want just this, or is there anything else I can help you with sir? Polish your boots sir?

Answer (score 0):

you need a nested IF statement in your B column

do this

```
   A                                      B
Access     =IF(A1 = "Access","Access Request",IF( A1 = "Deployment", "Deployment Request"))
```

Put that IF statement in your B column and it will check the contents of the A column and put the appropriate content in the B column for you.

"A1" is the cell you are checking. Assuming the "1, 2" down the left hand side of your data were just your row numbers and not actually a column of numbers.

drag that all the way down to do it for the entire column

this was quite simple I knew what you wanted but next time it might be better if you perhaps try find the answer yourself first and come here with what you have found so far. Then people can take it from there :)